# hide comment the moment a cell is filled with data

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

in my workbook, there's a worksheet named "Form", in cell B32 there is a comment stating that data entry is required - but after the data is inputed, the comment is still there, it is quite annoying.

How can I hide the ***comment*** the moment data is entered and unhide it if the cell is blank ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the code below to your "Form" worksheet module, for `Worksheet_Change` event.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Comm As Comment

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B32")) Is Nothing Then
    Set Comm = Target.Comment ' set the comment 

    If Target.Value <> "" Then ' if cell is not empty
        Comm.Delete ' delete the comment
    Else
        Comm.Visible = False ' hide the comment
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Comm As Comment

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B32")) Is Nothing Then

    Set Comm = Target.Comment ' set the comment

    If Comm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Comm.Visible = False    ' hide the comment
        Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlNoIndicator  ' also hide the indicator (unfortunately for the whole application)
    Else
        Comm.Visible = True ' hide the comment
        Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this worked fine...though ALL comment indicators are affected....it would be nice if only a particular cell comment indicator can be hidden..still it helps..Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can only display or hide the indicator on application level, just as I mentioned in the code

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest you don't use VBA. Instead, use Conditional Formatting to display a message in a cell alongside your data entry cell if that data entry cell is blank. This will still work if someone forgets to enable macros, and is exactly the kind of thing that Conditional Formatting was invented to do.

Something like this:

[image]

...which disappears as soon as something gets entered in that cell:

[image]

All you need is a very simple Conditional Formatting formula:

[image]

And also format the text fill of the warning cell white, so the warning message is invisible when the conditional format condition isn't triggered.

Or simply write a second conditional format condition, like so:

[image]

[image]